# With this rule , how can I say that the same field is greater than or less than 0?

Tags: php, mysql

Code php:

```
<td><?php echo $prod['gross_total'] >= 0 ?></td>
<td><?php echo $prod['gross_total'] <= 0 ?></td>
```

In the same field have the values ​​, $300, $350, $-100, want to get these values ​​and put on the table as higher values ​​for the left and lower values ​​for the right side of the table.
entries | outputs
$300    | $-100
$350

Comment: This field EVEN Returns hum specific value of the bank , I divide the table to the Highest value and the lowest value.

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your OP to add any new information.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Is this for book keeping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With the ternary operator you could use:**

```
$prod['gross_total']=-1;
echo $prod['gross_total']>0 ? 'more than 0' : 'less than or equal to 0';
```

the 3 parts are as follows:

1. Check for true/false
2. Do if True
3. Do if false

**With a switch you can do this:**

```
$prod['gross_total']=-1;
switch (TRUE) {
    case ($prod['gross_total']>0):
        //do this code
        echo "positive";
        break;
    case ($prod['gross_total']<0):
        //do this code
        echo "negative";
        break;
    default:
    //do nothing
        echo "neutral";
}
```

**With array sorting:**

```
$prod['gross_total']=array("1" => "3", "2" => "-1", "3" => "-4", "4" => "4");
asort($prod['gross_total']);
foreach ($prod['gross_total'] as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PHP's spaceship operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) to do multiple comparisons in one statement.

```
(expr) <=> (expr)
```

Returns `0` if both expressions are equal, `1` if the left is greater, and `-1` if the right is greater.  So you could use it like this:

```
echo $prod['gross_total'] <=> 0;

//echoes 0 if $prod['gross_total'] = 0,
//echoes 1 if $prod['gross_total'] > 0
//echoes -1 if $prod['gross_total'] < 0
```

Comment: Note: This only works for PHP 7.0+, it will not work if you are on older versions.